# Modal Content does not get refreshed, Bootstrap & tag-it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, tag-it

I am using tag-it.js on a bootstrap 3 website. I have a div where multiple items are loaded, each of them has a button to trigger a modal (single one on main page)

The click event gets a tag list from the db via ajax. Unfortunately this only works for the first time.

```
$(document).on('click','.modalTag',function(){

    var pID = "<?php echo $project[0]['pID'];?>";
    var file    = $(this).attr("data-filename");
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/admin/ajax/get_tags.php", 
        data: {file: file, pID: pID},
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#myTagsField').val(data);
            jQuery("#myTagsList").tagit({
                singleField: true,
                singleFieldNode: $('#myTagsField'),
                allowSpaces: true,
                minLength: 2,
                caseSensitive: false,
                removeConfirmation: true,
                tagSource: function( request, response ) {
                    //console.log("1");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/admin/search.php", 
                        data: { term:request.term },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.label+" ("+ item.id +")",
                                    value: item.value
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

When I click on a second button to get the tags for that specific item, it shows the initial one.

I also tried this:

```
$('#modalTag').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myTagsList").tagit("removeAll");
    });
```

but this only results in an empty list for the next opening.

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: have you tried like this `$('#modalTag').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {$(this).removeData('bs.modal');});`

Comment: same result, only shows the initial list. Do I have to initialize tag-it again somehow?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem, because, modal refresh itself when opening second time but it is not getting data to show, put `alert(pID);` in Ajax to check if click on second item, the id exist or not while opening modal again.

Comment: To close this: tag-it's destroy method does not work with my project, not sure why... Switched to tagEditor, works like a charm...